# WiFi Direct the right choice? Trying to make chat app - Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I'm trying to make a simple chat app on Android for learning purposes. I would like it to have the following features: Different "rooms" which people can create/join. Working of Bluetooth/WiFi Direct (Preferably WiFi direct). Passwords on rooms.

I'm having a number of problems however. I don't fully understand WiFi Direct. I've read and re-read the guides and references on developer.android.com and I've asked multiple times on #android-dev on freenode to no avail. Would someone be able to explain if what I outlined is even possible using WiFi direct and if not, what should I use?

TL;DR: Explain WiFi Direct's network structure and capabilities and provide resources for learning if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using WiFi direct.A room can be considerd a P2P group(1 group owner+ one or more clients) .The person who starts a "room" becomes a P2P group owner and whoever wants to join a group has to undergo the authenticatio process.A client can directly communicate with owner but to communicate with other clients in the group it has to go through the owner.

For detailed understanding of wifi direct better go through the wifi p2p tecnical specification v1.2 which can be found in WiFi alliance website under published specs. Or for a overview Click [here] (http://enjambre.it.uc3m.es/~agsaaved/papers/2012_camps_wircommag.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in theory but currently the framework of wifi-direct is too unreliable..

I have tried it and the connection is very unreliable ,it breaks abruptly for no reason. Also beyond 3 devices it doesn't scale very well ,though i tested it on tablets having very less processing power (maybe on good phones it might allow one or two more connections).

So i would recommend you use wifi for communication . it would be the best suited for your needs and easier to work with as well